# White space after moving uitabbar to the top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I use UINavigationcontroller inside UITabBarController and I have moved the UITabBar to the top .The UITabBar has moved successfully but the problem is, there is about 50px of white space where the tab bar used to be .
Anyone has a solution to this problem????

Comment: what do you mean by VC ?

Comment: The UINavigationController has UIViewController which contains a View and its height is 480

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this? Coz i am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

loop through the subviews of the tabbarcontroller.view until you find the container for the tabbar's inner views, then set the frame of that view to 50px higher than it currently is.

Alternatively, a better solution is not to try and use a tabbarcontroller this way. Just use a standalone UITabBar and implement your own view swapping logic when the tabs are tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck extended edges in rectangle.

[image]